# SSL certificate installation and binding

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate

I want to install and bind the wildcard ssl on 100+ servers, how to do that using powershell script?

Want powershell script to install and bind wildcard ssl on multiple servers. Or is there any Microsoft tool is there to bind ssl on multiple servers

Comment: Probably your company should take a look at this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-centralized-ssl-certificate-support-ssl-scalability-and-manageability BTW, server administration is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to place the certificate files (wildcard certificate, private key, and any intermediate certificates) on a central server that is accessible by all target servers.

You need to create a PowerShell script that will be executed on each target server. The script will copy the certificate file, install the certificate and bind it to the desired website.

You can then use PowerShell Remoting to execute the script on multiple servers simultaneously. To run a script on one or many remote computers, use the FilePath parameter of the Invoke-Command cmdlet. Also, you need to make sure you have the necessary permissions to run the script on the target server.

Also note that for different servers, the script may need to be modified based on different requirements and environments. It is recommended to test the script before applying it to the production server.

Reference document: [Windows PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.3#windows-powershell-remoting)